# Configuring dart content_shell on ubuntu trusty

Tags: ubuntu, dart, chromium, dartium

I am trying to run `xvfb-run -s '-screen 0 1024x768x24' pub run test -p content-shell` on Ubuntu Trusty.

Dart and content shell are installed in the following way:

```
# Install Dart
curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --import --no-default-keyring --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google.gpg
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dart_stable.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_stable.list
apt-get update
apt-get install --assume-yes  dart=1.15.0-1

# Content shell and dartium
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/dart-archive/channels/stable/release/1.15.0/dartium/dartium-linux-x64-release.zip> /dartium-linux-x64-release.zip && \
    unzip /dartium-linux-x64-release.zip -d /opt/google && \
    mv /opt/google/dartium-* /opt/google/dartium && \
    chmod -R 755 /opt/google/dartium

curl http://storage.googleapis.com/dart-archive/channels/stable/release/1.15.0/dartium/content_shell-linux-x64-release.zip > /content_shell-linux-x64-release.zip && \
    unzip /content_shell-linux-x64-release.zip -d /opt/google && \
    mv /opt/google/drt-* /opt/google/content_shell && \
    chmod -R 755 /opt/google/content_shell
```

with `/opt/google/content_shell` being included in my PATH variable.

```
# which content_shell
/opt/google/content_shell/content_shell
```

However, when I run that test attempt:

```
# xvfb-run -s '-screen 0 1024x768x24' pub run  test -p content-shell
```

I receive errors looking like:

```
Failed to run Content Shell: Content Shell failed with exit code 1..
  dart:async                              Future.Future.error
  package:async/src/result/error.dart 30  ErrorResult.asFuture
  package:async/src/result.dart 93        Result.release.<fn>
  ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
  dart:async                              _Future.then
  package:async/src/result.dart 93        Result.release
```

I do not see any more information. I am not sure if this should be concerning, though it looks ominous:

```
# content_shell --version
[1114:1114:0617/150811:9471556647:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(189)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
[1116:1116:0100/000000:9471568304:ERROR:zygote_linux.cc(612)] write: Broken pipe
```

My questions is how can I configure content shell to install correctly so it will run tests with `pub run test -p content-shell`?

Comment: This might be helpful https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-build/blob/master/lib/travis/build/script/dart.rb Usually problems are caused by missing fonts. Try to run content_shell directly to see if it produces any errors.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer that is for ubuntu precise, though I suppose I can try to find all those packages on trusty too...

Comment: I don't think there are concrete examples for different Ubuntu versions. On my debian system I just created a bunch of symlinks from missing fonts to arbitrary other fonts.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer is there any way to get more meaningful information out of contentshell to try to investigate more? I haven't figured out any way to get more useful debug logging either (which would probably help).

Comment: You can look up Chrome command line options and check if there is anything useful. I'd rather stick with Dartium and Chrome with xvfb which you need for content_shell as well anyway.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I was able to resolve this, `/opt/google/content_shell/content_shell.log` was showing me some suppressed errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, I needed some fonts.

You can see what errors contentshell has by viewing the log file, for my install location this is:

```
cat /opt/google/content_shell/content_shell.log
```

This showed me I was missing a bunch of fonts, which caused contentshell to silently fail.

The ones I had to install (or [hack my way around](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/26119#issuecomment-203040211) since a lot of the fonts packages are huge, and since this is a Docker container I wanted to minimize bloat):

```
apt-get update && apt-get install fonts-tlwg-garuda

# fix dart content shell
mkdir /usr/share/fonts/truetype/kochi
cd /usr/share/fonts/truetype/kochi
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf kochi-gothic.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf kochi-mincho.ttf

mkdir /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-indic-fonts-core/
cd /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-indic-fonts-core/
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf lohit_hi.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf lohit_ta.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf MuktiNarrow.ttf

mkdir /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-punjabi-fonts/
cd /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-punjabi-fonts/
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf lohit_pa.ttf
ln -s dejavu/ ttf-dejavu
cd /usr/share/fonts/truetype
ln -s dejavu/ ttf-dejavu

mkdir /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/
cd /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Arial.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Arial_Bold.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Arial_Bold_Italic.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Arial_Italic.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Comic_Sans_MS.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Comic_Sans_MS_Bold.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Courier_New.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Courier_New_Bold.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Courier_New_Bold_Italic.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Courier_New_Italic.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Georgia.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Georgia_Bold.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Georgia_Bold_Italic.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Georgia_Italic.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Impact.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Trebuchet_MS.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Trebuchet_MS_Bold_Italic.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Trebuchet_MS_Italic.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Times_New_Roman.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Times_New_Roman_Bold.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Times_New_Roman_Bold_Italic.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Times_New_Roman_Italic.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Verdana.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Verdana_Bold.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Verdana_Bold_Italic.ttf
ln -s ../dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf Verdana_Italic.ttf
```

Most of these were from [this source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/experimental/chromium/src/+/refs/wip/bajones/webvr/ui/gfx/test/fontconfig_util_linux.cc) validation. It's far easier to find the list it's validating first instead of running the command and seeing the next one a million times.

You may wish to actually install this package.