# Content-shell didn't run in docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dart, fedora

I use [this dockerfile](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rasarts/Whisper/3a0c35f3916fac2697bfcce1886988e47ad80eeb/Dockerfile). 
When i run: `docker run -it test_container pub run test -p content-shell`
I get `Failed to run Content Shell: Content Shell failed with exit code -6.`
When i tried call `content_shell` inside docker container it was be two errors:

> ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(189)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See... 
>   ERROR:zygote_linux.cc(612)] write: Broken pipe

On travis with [this config](https://travis-ci.org/Rasarts/Whisper/jobs/162461754/config) i got same errors for my tests: `Failed to run Content Shell: Content Shell failed with exit code 1..`

Can content_shell be run on the fedora or ubuntu?

Comment: Do you run `xvfb` somehow. I didn't see that in your dockerfile (only that it's installed).

Comment: This might also be related https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/27418

Comment: I just run `docker run -it test_container pub run test -p content-shell`. Like so.

Comment: Now i use [this config for travis](https://travis-ci.org/Rasarts/Whisper/jobs/162596532/config). I think i can use content-shell on fedora too.

Comment: I assume that doesn't run xvfb. You might need something like https://gist.github.com/jterrace/2911875 or https://github.com/mark-adams/docker-chromium-xvfb

Comment: Ok, thx. I will try

Comment: Now I add `#--- Installing Xvfb ---` section [in dockerfile](https://github.com/Rasarts/Whisper/blob/master/Dockerfile) And this [init.d for xvfb](https://gist.github.com/Rasarts/8e9919d7c202d4123bdeb3514962ad47) And error still there.

Comment: `Running without the SUID sandbox! ...` can be ignored. I don't know about the `Broken pipe` error. Can you try to run `content_shell` directly in the Plunker and see if you get a different error message?

Comment: Like so? [Image](http://i.imgur.com/gyfVqWt.png)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, but out of ideas now.

Comment: On [latest](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rasarts/Whisper/master/Dockerfile) ubuntu image I get `zygote_linux.cc(587)` [587 line](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/content/zygote/zygote_linux.cc) `fds.size`? What is fds can be?

Comment: Don't know. Maybe fileDescriptor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring dart content\_shell on ubuntu trusty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884934/configuring-dart-content-shell-on-ubuntu-trusty) -- you are experiencing similar issues to the ones I solved in my linked post.

Comment: [Yes, I tried before.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rasarts/Whisper/a939cfc753a47b941f5daa55c16debc262aa8cfb/Dockerfile) But not with ubuntu.